# How does Python PIL and PILLOW compress pictures?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I wanted to write a program with Python 3.3 in which a frame is added to a picture.
I use the PIL package from Python to do that. But the pictures I get are less than a third as big as the original and they loose quite some focus/sharpness/gloss. Where does Python compress/change the picture and how (if possible) can I subdue it?

I could think of some passages, which might be the one compressing.

1. I load the image with PIL:

   `img = Image.open(element)`
2. I create a new picture, which is black:

   `newImg = Image.new("RGB",(imgWidthNew,imgHightNew),(0,0,0,0))`
3. I create a pixel map out of my picture and change some:

   `pixels = newImg.load()`
4. I paste my picture into the middle of the black one:

   `newImg.paste (Image.open(element), (halfFrameWidth, halfFrameHight, imgWidth+halfFrameWidth, imgHight+halfFrameHight))`
5. The new image is beeing saved:

   `newImg.save(path,dpi=[300,300])`

I load mostly .jpg pictures, but due to some problems I extract .bmp files.

```
 path = path[:path.rfind(".")] + fileEnding
```

But this shouldnt be the problem, because I have the same issues without changing the data type.
My operating system is Windows7 64BIT and I use Pillow 2.3.0 with Python 3.3.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is the image being pasted at its original size, or is it being made smaller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When saving as JPEG, you can set the quality parameter to control the amount of compression:

```
newImg.save(path, 'JPEG', dpi=[300,300], quality=90)
```

Or, save in a lossless format, such as PNG:

```
newImg.save(path, 'PNG', dpi=[300,300])
```

Comment: Make sure the `path` extension and the format match each other or you'll run into some trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is helpfull for sure. But I also found by accident why the lossless format PNG looked blurred on my screen, after I zoomed in a little. The original is in a prefect size for my screen, while the file I edited is not. When I zoom in, I get a perfect format for this picture and it looks just as good as the other one.

Thank you eiter way, I think of using JPEG now.